# Long PHP script does not run completely

Tags: php, magento, integration

**Problem**

I'm trying to execute a script in PHP that reads a CSV file and for each row that the script reads it gets the code to verify if it already exists in the database. If this code exists in the database update the stock, if not exists just insert into DB.

My CSV file has 700+ lines, each line executes at least 2 queries so the integration page times out.

**ATTEMPS**
Created a .htaccess file that disable GZIP.

```
SetEnv no-gzip 1
```

Set my time limit to over 1000+

set_time_limit(9999999999);

**What is happening**

When I run the script it reads 40 lines and stops executing and stops loading.

EDIT

For each row execute this code:

```
if ($produto->getId()) {
    $stock = $produto->getStockData();
    $stock['qty'] = $quantidade;
    $stock['is_in_stock'] = $this->initStock($quantidade);
    $stock['manage_stock'] = 1;
    $stock['use_config_manage_stock'] = 1;
    if ($altura > 0)
        $produto->setData('volume_altura', $altura);
    if ($comprimento > 0)
        $produto->setData('volume_comprimento', $comprimento);
    if ($largura > 0)
        $produto->setData('volume_largura', $largura);
    $produto->setData('weight', $this->initWeight($peso));
    $produto->setStockData($stock);

    if ($produto->save()) {
       $this->showLog('<EDIT> Produto com código [' . $codigo . '] editado com sucesso.', true);
       $this->writeLog('<EDIT> Produto com código [' . $codigo . '] editado com sucesso.');
    } else {
        $this->showLog('<EDIT> Não foi possível editar o produto com código [' . $codigo . ']', false);
        $this->writeLog('<EDIT> Não foi possível editar o produto com código [' . $codigo . ']');
    }
} else {
    $produto = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $produto->setTypeId('simple');
    $produto->setAttributeSetId(4);
    $produto->setData('tax_class_id', 0);
    $produto->setVisibility(1);
    $produto->setStatus(1);
    $produto->setData('sku', $sku);
    $produto->setData('color', $cor);
    $produto->setData('name', utf8_encode($descricao));
    $produto->setData('marca', $this->initAttribute(148, $marca));
    $produto->setData('codigo_barra', $codBarra);
    $produto->setData('price', $preco);
    if ($altura > 0)
        $produto->setData('volume_altura', $altura);
    if ($comprimento > 0)
        $produto->setData('volume_comprimento', $comprimento);
    if ($largura > 0)
        $produto->setData('volume_largura', $largura);
        $produto->setData('cost', $custo);
        $stock['qty'] = $quantidade;
        $stock['is_in_stock'] = $this->initStock($quantidade);
        $stock['manage_stock'] = 1;
        $stock['use_config_manage_stock'] = 1;
        $produto->setStockData($stock);
        $produto->setData('weight', $this->initWeight($peso));

        if ($produto->save()) {
            $this->showLog('<NEW> O produto com código [' . $codigo . '] foi adicionado com sucesso.', true);
            $this->writeLog('<NEW> O produto com código [' . $codigo . '] foi adicionado com sucesso.');
        } else {
            $this->showLog('<NEW> - Não foi possível adicionar o produto com código [' . $codigo . ']', false);
            $this->writeLog('<NEW> - Não foi possível adicionar o produto com código [' . $codigo . ']');
        }
}
```

SOLVED:

I found an OB_START() in the beginning of my code, and I wasn't using ob. When I removed the script back to works fine.

Comment: Are those queries optimized for such a thing? Can you see any errors in the log file?

Comment: Could you include your queries?

Comment: seems you have to increase max_execution_time

Comment: @Epodax i edit and insert the code that do the queries.

Comment: does it always stop at 40, or sometimes more sometimes less?

Comment: Do you have error_reporting(E_ALL) set?

Comment: @Augwa between 40~50

Comment: @Patrick insert it now and nothing happens, no errors :/

Comment: I would start manually outputting the data in the csv and see if it stops parsing the csv at a certain point

Comment: perhaps you're running out of memory, try `ini_set('memory_limit','512M');` if that lets further perhaps you need to do some garbage collection.

Comment: @Patrick Understood, i will try it know.

Comment: @Augwa Hmm, dont work, i will try debug each line, i thing is something with a line between 40~50

Comment: @Patrick i've tried to execute 1 by one, i run 1 to 70 and no errors, but when i execute all 760 in a row just 46 products update :(

Comment: unless it's consistently the exact same line for the same file, it's extremely the CSV is the problem. It's either a timeout or memory issue. I know magento can be a memory hog, so it's likely to be that. What if you do your import without using magento object hydration and insert directly into the db?

Comment: It sounds like you may have a memory issue, you should output the memory_get_usage() & memory_get_peak_usage() in each iteration.  If this is constantly getting bigger, then you'd need to either garbage collect or break the csv into smaller chunks (or define offsets to start processing)

Comment: @Patrick Thanks Man that makes me find the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have an exceptionally large/inefficient database/queries running 1400 queries should not take so long that it times out.

If possible, run the script as a cli script and see what is output and how long it takes to run (there is no max execution time on a cli script).

You need to at least include pseudo-code so that we can help debug it.

For more debugging, add lines of output in each iteration and flush the output buffer.  That will ensure the page doesn't timeout.

Comment: I've tried cron jobs too, the code stop in 40 ~ 50.

Comment: I would start logging out all the data that you are manipulating and see if there are obvious issues with the data you are trying to save.

Comment: you want to check the csv file?